# iOS DateFormatter Returns Null

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I want to get day/month and hour:minute from "12/10/2015 6:11:04 PM" format date. I am from Turkey so our date format is 23 hours. When I use the code below, it returns date "nil".

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"tr_TR_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/10/2015 6:11:04 PM"];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```

Comment: Your date formatter pattern is wrong - [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];  Try: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];  This should correspond to '12/10/2015 6:11:04 PM'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change dateformat like and try

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
```

Comment: once print what the result you get here `NSDate *date`